# Wipers not working on timer

Tags: windshield-wipers

Today it was raining in Manchester so I turned the wiper on the timer setting. You know the one that only occasionally wipes the windshield. HOwever I drove many miles without it moving once.  Other continuous settings work fine.

After switch it on and off many times it did move once but most of the time it didn't budge. I have had the indicator switch go shortcircuit on me. Could this have happened to the wiper switch this time? Is there any basic troubleshooting I can do? I have basic electronics knowledge and a cheapy multimeter which apparently is capable upto 10Amps

Comment: Do wipers work when set to wipe continuously in slower and faster modes?

Comment: yes it works perfectly. Polo 1 litre 2001 sorry I omitted that info. Y Registration

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the relay for the wiper timing is on the fritz. It's a possibility that it could be in the switch itself, but you also wouldn't be able to turn it on continuous mode if it were the switch. It's either a blown fuse leading to the relay, or the relay itself.

Comment: how do determine the fuse that leads to the relay? If it is the relay where would it be? Is it something I can do. Bear in mind am no mechanic.

Comment: If it's a blown fuse, it would more than likely be in the fuse panel inside of your car. The relay panel is *usually* found under the hood of the car, next to the computer. The way the relay works and is wired depends on the car. You can always try replacing it if there is one, but it's not guaranteed to work. If the relay isn't getting power, then you've got a short somewhere. Again, the wiring depends upon the car. I tried to get the Polo mechanic manual for you from [here](http://erwin.volkswagen.de), but you apparently have to enter into a contract with Volkswagen to get the manuals.

Comment: fuses are easy to check if blown. if in doubt, check all your fuses (http://www.haynes.co.uk/wcsstore/HaynesPublishing/images/features/051007_ChangeFusePR_2_small.jpg). if the fuse(s) are in good shape then just replace the relay. they tend to be relatively cheap.